# best way to store a JWT inside a httpOnly cookie

Tags: go, cookies, jwt

I've found the [SecureCookie](https://github.com/gorilla/securecookie) Module and I'd like to use it to store JWT Tokens (access & refresh) inside a httpOnly Cookie to be used in a REST API.

The following code is cited from the official Github page mentioned above - I am not sure what the "value string map" is meant for:

```
func SetCookieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    value := map[string]string{
        "foo": "bar",
    }
    if encoded, err := s.Encode("cookie-name", value); err == nil {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{
            Name:  "cookie-name",
            Value: encoded,
            Path:  "/",
            Secure: true,
            HttpOnly: true,
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    }
}
```

In other words: Where should I save my tokens? Would they go to the "value" string map or should they be properties in the "cookie" object that's created after the encode function?

Just to mention it: I'm also using the Gin framework, but that shouldn't change anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing SecureCookie does is converting your token value into an encoded string.
Then you can treat it as a new value for your token when setting cookie to client.

The `Encode` can work with any data type, not always must be a `map[string]string`, you can pass the jwt token to it directly.

```
encoded, err := s.Encode("jwt-token", "value.of.jwt.token.here")
```

After that, can't be simpler than a key-value format as in the example:

```
    cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "jwt-token", // <- should be any unique key you want
        Value:    encoded, // <- the token after encoded by SecureCookie
        Path:     "/",
        Secure:   true,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

Remember to decode the `encoded` cookie with the correct key `jwt-token` when you wanna verify the token again.